# Attaching SQL Server Express DB using VB.Net Code

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using the following VB code to attach my DBs to server.

```
Dim cnnConnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" & Application.StartupPath + "\datafiles\" + TextBox1.Text + ".mdf" & ";Integrated Security=True;Database='" & TextBox1.Text & "';Connect Timeout=30")
    cnnConnection.Open()
```

But it gives an error:

Unable to open the physical file "D:.Net Programs\SQLDBAttachExperiments\SQLDBAttachExperiments\bin\Debug\datafiles\dbSQLtest.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(error not found)". Cannot attach the file 'D:.Net Programs\SQLDBAttachExperiments\SQLDBAttachExperiments\bin\Debug\datafiles\dbSQLtest.mdf' as database 'dbSQLtest'.

How to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be due to the fact that the file is already opened due to some error while establishing the connection so establish the connection like below

```
Using con As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("YourConnection string")
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    Dim expression As String = "Parameter value"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = "Your Stored Procedure"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Your Parameter Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = expression
    cmd.Connection = con
    Using dr As IDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.Read() Then
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```